# Power loss due to mismatch impedance connector in coaxial line

Tags: connector, coax, loss

[image]
Not being an electronics professional but face the following problem I hope you can help me.
I would like to estimate the losses due to an impedance mismatch of connector used in wall-crossing of a coaxial transmission line.

Unfortunately, I do not have the experimental resources for testing the connector (with network analyzer).

Is it possible with analytical formula or with simulations?

Comment: Fix the image, show where coax screens are grounded/connected and explain what 6nnn means in your incorrectly orientated picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mismatch loss is almost certainly half of nothing, the connectors length being negligible compared to the ~2M electrical wavelength.

However, if that is an N type, be careful, 50R and 75R N types are NOT compatible and trying will either damage the female or make unreliable contact (depending on which way you try it), the centre pin geometry is different.